Stripe and Next 14 - Why is the PaymentElement not showing?
There don't appear to be any errors and as far as I can tell my setup is correct. I have my server-side code in the page component:
https://github.com/erasebegin/heard-good-things-shop/blob/main/src/app/%5Bslug%5D/checkout/page.tsx
I have the provider in a client component as a child of page.tsx:
https://github.com/erasebegin/heard-good-things-shop/blob/main/src/app/%5Bslug%5D/components/StripeWrapper.tsx
And then I have the PaymentElement inside the components that is wrapped by StripeWrapper:
https://github.com/erasebegin/heard-good-things-shop/blob/main/src/app/%5Bslug%5D/components/StripeCheckout.tsx
I've had a similar issue previously where the PaymentElement didn't appear and that was to do with the Stripe promise not coming through correctly, but from what I can tell everything is going where it needs to go so why am I not seeing the PaymentElement?
Any insight would be greatly appreciated!
P.S. I thought I'd use links to the code to be more succinct. Would pasting the code into the question be preferable?

Payment intent should be created at server. Private key also shouldn't be set in the component for security concern. I'd recommend checking the guide here for Payment Element integration.

Thanks for your response :) Have you worked with React Server Components before? The payment intent is being created on the server as that is a server component. The children are client components and they are not accessing the private key.

You're on the right track but are mixing the concepts a little, the commented Yuting is also half right.
I see in StripeCheckout.tsx you have the handle submit on the client side.
Even though you have correctly initialised stripe on the server side with the Private key, you "could" then pass it to a client component however you would then be exposing server secrets. You need to keep the stripe content entirely not he server.
The way to achieve this traditionally is to expose a small api. Now the react server components approach could involve a server side form aka "Server action"
Vercel have a helpful guide on this: https://vercel.com/guides/getting-started-with-nextjs-typescript-stripe
Essentially rather than what you have here:
 const handleSubmit = async (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    // We don't want to let default form submission happen here,
    // which would refresh the page.
    event.preventDefault();

You would have something like this:
"use server"
const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Create a Checkout Session.
  const checkoutSession: Stripe.Checkout.Session = await fetchPostJSON(
    '/api/checkout_sessions',
    { amount: input.customDonation },
  );

  if ((checkoutSession as any).statusCode === 500) {
    console.error((checkoutSession as any).message);
    return;
  }

  // Redirect to Checkout.
  const stripe = await getStripe();
  const { error } = await stripe!.redirectToCheckout({
    // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
    // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
    // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
    sessionId: checkoutSession.id,
  });
  // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
  // error, display the localized error message to your customer
  // using `error.message`.
  console.warn(error.message);
};


Thank you for your response. You're right a server action would work well here, it's just a function that I lifted directly from the Stripe docs and hadn't tested it because the payment form isn't showing up. I don't think your solution relates to the problem I am having and would have no effect on whether or not the form is showing since the function isn't being called unless a button is clicked on.
